# ActiveMQ AJax Client

Tags: ajax, web-applications, client, activemq-classic

I try to write a simple Ajax client to send and receive messages. It's successfully deployed but I have never received msg from the client. I am beating myself to think out what I am missing, but still can't make it work.

Here is my code:

1. I creat a dynamic web application named: ActiveMQAjaxService and put activemq-web.jar and all neccessary dependencies in the WEB-INF/lib folder. In this way, AjaxServlet and MessageServlet will be deployed
2. I start activemq server in command line: ./activemq => activemq successfully created and display:

> Listening for connections at: tcp://lilyubuntu:61616 
>   INFO | Connector openwire Started 
>    INFO | ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker (localhost, ID:lilyubuntu-56855-1272317001405-0:0) started 
>    INFO | Logging to org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog 
>    INFO | jetty-6.1.9 
>    INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole initialized. 
>    INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' 
>    INFO | ActiveMQ Console at http://0.0.0.0:8161/admin
>    INFO | Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext 
>    INFO | Connector vm://localhost Started 
>    INFO | Camel Console at http://0.0.0.0:8161/camel
>    INFO | ActiveMQ Web Demos at http://0.0.0.0:8161/demo
>    INFO | RESTful file access application at http://0.0.0.0:8161/fileserver
>    INFO | Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8161

3) index.xml, which is the html to test the client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="amq/amq.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">amq.uri='amq';</script> 
<title>Hello Ajax ActiveMQ</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<p>Hello World!</p> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
amq.sendMessage("topic://myDetector", "message"); 
var myHandler = 
{   
  rcvMessage: function(message) 
  { 
     alert("received "+message); 
  } 
}; 

function myPoll(first) 
{ 
        if (first) 
        { 
                amq.addListener('myDetector', 'topic://myDetector', myHandler.rcvMessage); 
        } 
}
```

amq.addPollHandler(myPoll);

4) Web.xml:

```
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
limitations under the License.
```

-->

```
<display-name>ActiveMQ Web Demos</display-name> 
<description> 
Apache ActiveMQ Web Demos 
</description> 

<!-- context config --> 
<context-param> 
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.brokerURL</param-name> 
    <param-value>vm://localhost</param-value> (I also tried tcp://localhost:61616) 
    <description>The URL of the Message Broker to connect to</description> 
</context-param> 

<context-param> 
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.embeddedBroker</param-name> 
    <param-value>true</param-value> 
    <description>Whether we should include an embedded broker or not</description> 
</context-param> 

<!-- servlet mappings --> 

<!-- the subscription REST servlet --> 
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet</servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 

<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServlet</servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
    <!-- 
    Uncomment this parameter if you plan to use multiple consumers over REST 
    <init-param> 
            <param-name>destinationOptions</param-name> 
            <param-value>consumer.prefetchSize=1</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    --> 

</servlet> 

<!-- the queue browse servlet --> 
<filter> 
  <filter-name>session</filter-name> 
  <filter-class>org.apache.activemq.web.SessionFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 

<filter-mapping> 
  <filter-name>session</filter-name> 
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

After all of these, I deploy the web-app, and it's successfully deployed, but when I try it out in http://localhost:8080/ActiveMQAjaxService/index.html , nothing happens.

I can run the demo portfolioPublisher demo successfully at http://localhost:8161/demo/portfolio/portfolio.html, and see the numbers updated all the time. But for my simple web-app, nothing really works.

Any suggestion/hint is welcomed. Thanks so much

Lily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to the management [web console](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html); web-page, and seeing if you can send a message to your broker from that context, that might go along way towards directing you towards the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I set up the `web.xml` in web application as following and it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>msg_tomcat_activemq</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.activemq.brokerURL</param-name>
        <param-value>tcp://192.168.1.105:61616</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.activemq.embeddedBroker</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

     </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/amq/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/message/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<filter>
      <filter-name>session</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>session</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.activemq.web.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```